# JavaScript перестал работать

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

И так пользуюсь phpDesigner 7. 
 Установлен денвер, сайт стоит, все работает. 
 К главной страничке подключил библиотеку jQuery:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Так же создал файл для яваскриптов и тоже его подключил:

```
 <script src="js/myscripts2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Внутри этого файла написал код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var myLink = $('img[scr*=logo.jpg]'); 
 myLink.hide(3000);

 });
```

//шапка исчезает 
 в коде ошибки нет, все указано правильно и он работал и как только и дописал еще некую часть в код и сохранил его то все перестало работать. 
 То есть что бы я не писал в этом файле, какой бы яваскрипт он не работает. 
 Пробовал перезакидать проект на пшпДизайнере, создавал новый файл с яваскриптом, денвер перезагружал, перезагрузка компа, нечего не помогло. 
 Что это?)

Comment: Вы же сами на свой вопрос ответили. )) Всё работает до тех пор, пока вы не начинаете писать еще какой-то код. Т.е. проблема не в phpDesigner, не в Denwer, а в ваших скриптах.

Ваш К.О.

Answer (score 1):

Возвращайся в изменениях пока не заработает.